# С++ вместо 0.0 выводит -0.0

Tags: c++

Сначала вместо нуля выводил экспоненту, поставил в сout setprecision(1) выводит -0.0 как с этим бороться? И как вместо nan вывести "*"

```
    cout << "  \  X |" << endl;
    cout << "   \   |" << endl;
    cout << " Y  \  |";
    double z,x=0.2,y=0.2,a=-1,b=1,c=-1, d=1;
    for (a=-1; a < b; a+=x)
    {
        cout.setf(ios_base::fixed);
        cout << setprecision(1) << a << "|";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (c=-1; c < d; c+=y)
    {
        cout.setf(ios_base::fixed);
        cout << setprecision(1) << c << "|";

        for (a=-1; a<b; a+=x)
        {
            z= (sqrt(a+c))/(a*c);
            cout << z << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

[image: подробнее]

Comment: Так а может там число отрицательное, допустим -0,0005, а младшие разряды отрезаются. А nan быть вообще не должно, исправляйте свои вычисления.

Comment: [Как задавать вопросы,MCVE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: а как мне тогда сделать так что бы выводилось от -1 до 1 с шагом 0.2 и выводился именно 0.0. В примере решения этой задачи вместо нан у пользователя выводит *. вот пример http://ibb.co/eDPmBS

Comment: @РоманУмбетов, округляйте до 1-го знака после запятой.

Comment: так он и окргляется до 1 знака

Comment: Добавьте что-то типа `a = round(a*10.0)/10.0;`

Comment: Без  толку убрав cout.setf(ios_base::fixed); выдает экспоненту вместо 0